# Postgres (auto) vacuum vs MySQL REPAIR TABLE

Tags: mysql, postgresql, maintenance

What are the differences between them? They have the same purposes?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html

Answer (score 1):

`REPAIR TABLE` is used to try to fix broken non-crash-safe MyISAM tables, see [`REPAIR TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html). It's totally unrelated.

I'm assuming you really meant `OPTIMIZE TABLE` since that's what you link to.

If so, they're somewhat related, but MySQL's `OPTIMIZE TABLE` more similar to PostgreSQL's `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER` command in that it actively compacts the table.

Normal `VACUUM` just marks space as ready for re-use. I'm not sure that InnoDB has any equivalent, and MyISAM certainly does not.